# Use base color as default for image texture

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, color, base-color

I have set a base color to the material of my object:
[image]

Later on I decide to use an image texture and the base color is gone:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to set a new image texture whose default color will be my selected base color instead of the default black?

Answer (score 0):

the texture overrides the base color, you can paint the texture the color you want instead

Comment: Right, but what if I had already picked a color I liked. What would be a good way to instruct the texture color to be the exact color that was once the base color?

Comment: you can unplug the texture, copy the color code, and make the texture the same color as before!

Comment: No need to copy the color code, before creating a new texture you could hover over the _Base Color_'s color field, press `Ctrl`+`C` to copy the color, then when creating the new texture, hover over the black color field and `Ctrl`+`V` to paste the color.

Comment: Thank you @GordonBrinkmann! This is exactly what I needed